# backbone.js render multi livel ul-list from JSON

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am getting collection of objects from the server.

```
[
 {"id":1,"name":"test1","parent_id":null},
 {"id":2,"name":"test2","parent_id":null},
 {"id":3,"name":"test3","parent_id":2},
 {"id":4,"name":"test4","parent_id":2}
]
```

I want to transform json into ul-list

```
<ul>
  <li>test1</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      test2
      <li>test3</li>
      <li>test4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How I can render it?

Comment: your html doesn't look right. the nested UL should be within the second li.

Answer (score 4):

After playing around allot with the fiddle given by fguillen. I have finally solved my problem and in turn also solution for main question here.

My personal task was to create  [bootstrap tabs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs) using backbone.js.

Please go through this fiddle here: [Nested-Unordered list](http://goo.gl/cgzY6)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you explain us how you organized your app we may better answer you.

So far, what I can say is that the best strategy is to render the models one by one.
Look at the [todo example code](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/examples/todos/todos.js) to better understand what I'm talking about.

I also assume you use jquery.

In that example you have, in the main app, a function which applies to the whole collection (addAll), and another which applies on the single models.

```
// Add all items in the **Todos** collection at once.
addAll: function() {
  MYCOLLECTION.each(this.addOne);
},

addOne: function(todo) {
  var view = new TodoView({model: MYMODEL});
  this.$("#list").append(view.render().el);
},
```

In this framework, all you need to do is  some coding in the view.render() in the view of the single model function, like this

```
  el:$('ul .test0'),
  render: function() {
  if (!_.isNull(this.model.get('parent_id')) ){
      if($("." + this.model.get('parent_id')).length == 0) { 
        //the class doesn't exist because the <ul> hasn't been created yet
        //so create the <ul> tag
        $('#'+this.model.get('parent_id')).append("<ul class='"+this.model.get('id')+"'></ul>");
        }
      //now append the <li> element
      $('.'+this.model.get('parent_id')).append("<li id='"+this.model.get('id')+"'>"+this.model.get('name')+"</li>");
      }
  else{
        $(this.el).append("<li id='"+this.model.get('id')+"'>"+this.model.get('name')+"</li>");
        }
  this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
  this.$el.toggleClass('done', this.model.get('done'));
  this.input = this.$('.edit');
  return this;
},
```

At the end you'll have a list like this

```
 <ul class='1'>
   <li id='1'>test1</li>
   <li id='2'>test2</li>
   <ul class='2'>
     <li id='3'>test3</li>
     <li id='4'>test4</li>
   </ul>
 </ul>
```

Get the idea?
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

@DanieleB has been faster than me :).. but still I'm going to expose my approach wich I think is very similar:

```
var data = [
  {"id":1,"name":"test1","parent_id":null},
  {"id":2,"name":"test2","parent_id":null},
  {"id":3,"name":"test3","parent_id":2},
  {"id":4,"name":"test4","parent_id":2}
]

var NestedView = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function(){
    this.$el.html( "<ul id='ul-null'></ul>" )
    this.collection.each( function( model ){ this.renderElement( model ) }, this )
  },

  renderElement: function( model ){
    var ul = this.getParentUl( model );
    this.appendElement( ul, model );
  },

  getParentUl: function( model ) {
    var ul = this.$el.find( "#ul-" + model.get( "parent_id" ) );
    if( ul.length == 0 ) {
      this.appendListInElement( model );
      ul = this.$el.find( "#ul-" + model.get( "parent_id" ) );
    }

    return ul;
  },

  appendListInElement: function( model ){
    var li = this.$el.find( "#li-" + model.get( "parent_id" ) );
    li.after( "<ul id='ul-" + model.get( "parent_id" ) + "'></ul>" );
  },

  appendElement: function( ul, model ){
    ul.append( "<li id='li-" + model.get( "id" ) + "'>" + model.get( "name" ) + "</li>" );
  }
});

var elements = new Backbone.Collection( data );
var nestedView = new NestedView({ el: "#wrapper", collection: elements });
nestedView.render();
​
​
```

[Check the jsfiddle in work](http://jsfiddle.net/fguillen/7exR2/)